# Ramanujan's sum bounded

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

Is there a simple proof why Ramanujan's sum $\vert c_n(a) \vert \leqslant a$, when $a \in \mathbb N$. I found this statement, but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: $c_n(a)=\sum\limits_{k=1,(k,n)=1}^n \exp(i2\pi \frac{ak}{n})$

Comment: Everything is explained on [wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum#von_Sterneck) (and be careful, their notations use $n$ for $a$)

Comment: The main step in the proof is $\eta_n(a) = \sum_{k=1}^n e^{2i \pi a k /n} = n \ 1_{n | a}$ and $\eta_n(a) = \sum_{d | n} c_n(a)  \implies $ by Möbius inversion and letting $g = gcd(n,a) $, assuming $gcd(g,n/g)= 1$ : $$c_n(a) =  \sum_{d | n} \mu(n/d) \eta_{d}(a) = \sum_{d | n} \mu(n/d) d \ 1_{d | a} = \mu(n/g) \sum_{d | g} \mu(g/d) d = \mu(\frac{n}{gcd(n,a)}) \phi(gcd(n,a))$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the limitation can be seen with the formula

$$c_n(a):=\sum\limits_{k=1,(k,n)=1}^n \exp(i2\pi \frac{ak}{n})=\varphi(n)\frac{\mu(\frac{n}{gcd(n,a)})}{\varphi(\frac{n}{gcd(n,a)})} \enspace.$$

Be $\enspace\displaystyle n=\prod\limits_{k=1}^r p_k^{a_k}\enspace$  and $\enspace\displaystyle gcd(n,a)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^s p_k^{b_k}\enspace$ ordered by common prime factors with $\enspace s\leq r\enspace$, $\enspace 1\leq b_k\leq a_k\enspace$ and $\enspace\displaystyle  c_k:=(1|_{a_k=b_k} \vee 0|_{a_k\neq b_k})$ .

It follows  $$c_n(a)=\mu(\frac{n}{gcd(n,a)}) gcd(n,a)\prod\limits_{k=1}^r(1-\frac{1}{p_k})^{1-c_k}$$
and therefore $\enspace|c_n(a)|\leq gcd(n,a)\enspace$.

Comment: I think $\sum\limits_{k=1,(k,n)=1}^a \exp(i2\pi \frac{ak}{n})$ should be  $\sum\limits_{k=1,(k,n)=1}^n \exp(i2\pi \frac{ak}{n})$. So by bounding the absolute value with 1 you only get $\vert \sum\limits_{k=1,(k,n)=1}^n \exp(i2\pi \frac{ak}{n}) \vert \leq \varphi(n) $ but they state that its $\leq a$.

Comment: @Elq : Thanks, I have corrected.

Comment: did you check if it fits [wikipedia's result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum#von_Sterneck) ?

Comment: @user1952009  : Which wiki-result do you mean ? Or you have found any contradiction or mistake which I should check ?

Comment: @user1952009 : I couldn't find a problem with the notations. But I am open to any criticism or improvement suggestion.

Comment: my suggestion was to compare with wikipedia :)

Comment: and I voted to reopen the question

Comment: @user1952009 : I've done the compare a minute ago. :-)